# Не подключается библиотека OpenCV на Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv

Всем привет !

Хочу установить и работать с библиотекой `OpenCV` на `Mac`.
Проделал все, так как описано в [этом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37RvqZVddAw) туториале. Написал следующий код:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Main {

    static {
        try {
            System.load("/Users/nikto92/Documents/opencv-2.4.13/release/bin/opencv_java2413.jar");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
          System.exit(1);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String argv[]) 
      {
          System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
          Mat mat = Mat.eye( 3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
          System.out.println( "mat = " + mat.dump() );
      }
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> Native code library failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Can't load library:
>   /Users/nikto92/Documents/opencv-2.4.13/release/bin/opencv_java2413.jar

Что я сделал не так ?

За ответ буду очень признателен. Спасибо !

Comment: так либ нет)))  Какая версия macOS??? и каку версию OpenCV  инсталил??

Comment: @Akuma925 opencv-2.4.13, mac os mavericks

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно пересобрать либы вот инструкция  :

- Установка CMake Прежде всего, необходимо загрузить DMG-файл бинарного
  дистрибутива [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) . После завершения установки вам будет
  предложено помесить CMake в `/usr/bin` , выберите Да и закончите
  установку Для проверки того, что CMake был успешно установлен,
  наберите в Терминале

  CMake -version
- Установка OpenCV
  Во-первых, загрузите исходные файлы стабильной версии [OpenCV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/) (в моем случае 2.4.7) 
  Извлеките файлы в папку и перейдите в эту папку через терминал, например

  cd ~/Downloads
  tar -xvf opencv-2.4.7.tar
  cd opencv-2.4.7
- Теперь, произведем сборку и установку OpenCV в Терминале, следующие команды должен быть успешно выполнены (без ошибок)

  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
  make -j8
  sudo make install

Comment: Появился вопрос со второго этапа:
если я хочу использовать на MacOS эту либу но не для iOS, мне нужно скачивать для iOS или для Linux ?

Comment: нет, вы просто собираете себе openCV под целевую систему (не важно macos linux,windows,ios,android,BSD) под что соберете под тем и будет работать.